# How to change a range of column names in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The column names of my dataframe looks like:

```
Country Code 1900.0 1901.0 1902.0 1903.0 1904.0......
```

Now I would like to change the numbers from float type to string, so I use:

```
df.columns[2:] = [str(int(x)) for x in df.columns[2:]]
```

but it shows error:

```
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

I know I can use dict to change column names, but what if there are too many names having to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary from your list comprehension and use that to rename the columns:

```
df.rename(columns={x: str(int(x)) for x in df.columns[2:]}, inplace=True)
```

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[1900.0,1901.0,1902.0,1903.0,1904.0,1906.0])
df.rename(columns={x: str(int(x)) for x in df.columns[2:]}, inplace=True)
```

Result:

```
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [1900.0, 1901.0, 1902, 1903, 1904, 1906]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `df.columns`, it returns an Index type object, which you cannot use list comprehension on (hence the error). I would suggest making a variable `cols` which is the column names as a list, change the floats to strings in this list then re-assign to the columns as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Country', 'Code', 1900.0, 1901.0, 1902.0, 1903.0, 1904.0])
cols = df.columns.to_list()
cols[2:] = [str(int(x)) for x in cols[2:]]
df.columns = cols
```

Output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Country, Code, 1900, 1901, 1902, 1903, 1904]
Index: []
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure why you're getting that error. I'm also not sure what you were trying to do with the [2:] inside and outside your expression.

When you do the int(x) it deletes the decimals in the number. If you have a list of floats and want to convert them to string you can simply do:

```
list_of_strings_with_decimals = [str(x) for x in list_of_floats]
```

If you want to get rid of the decimals you can do it like this:

```
list_of_strings_without_decimals = [str(int(x)) for x in list_of_floats]
```